# Toggle checkbox button not working

Tags: html, css

I was just making a custom `checkbox` button and ended up with this , **[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jakecigar/xtayoqmr/)**.

**HTML**:

```
 <input type=checkbox id="a">
  <label for="a">
    <button>click me</button>
  </label>
```

**CSS**:

```
#a {
    display:none;
}
#a ~ label button {
    background:yellow;
}
#a:checked ~ label button {
    background:red;
}
```

But this does't work , WHY ? I want to know WHY it does't work.

if i remove the `button` and check the styling to as follows:

```
#a {
    display:none;
}
#a ~ label {
    background:yellow;
}
#a:checked ~ label {
    background:red;
}
```

It works fine. **Can anybody answer why my initial code does't work.**

Comment: If I replace css in you fiddler with your working code. it still doesn't work, does it?

Comment: Can you check all the answers ?

Comment: why set #a display to none? also I think you should use quotation type="checkbox"

Comment: @Arvaan ebilgin pointed out in his answer that if you replace button with span , it works , also if you remove the button and just keep the label it works , http://jsfiddle.net/xtayoqmr/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems you're trying to understand **why** it doesn't work, and not what's the solution.

Your code doesn't work because the label's action doesn't propagate to child elements that have custom click behaviors. So, when you put a button inside it, or an anchor etc, it won't work.

Not automatically, at least.

But if you want to make the button change your checkbox value, you can add a click event to it, and then propagate that click to the checkbox:

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.target.parentNode.click(); // propagate the click event to the label
});
```

```css
#a {
    display:none
}
#a ~ label button {
    background:yellow
}
#a:checked ~ label button {
    background:red
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id="a">
<label for="a">
    <button>click me</button>
</label>
```

---

If you need a CSS-only solution, there is some kind of hack you can do, by disabling all the mouse events of the button, using the `pointer-events: none` inside your css:

```css
#a {
    display:none
}
#a ~ label button {
    background:yellow;
    pointer-events: none
}
#a:checked ~ label button {
    background:red
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox id="a">
<label for="a">
    <button>click me</button>
</label>
```

Comment: plus one , but looking for a css only solution !

Comment: Your question is tagged javascript / jQuery... And using a button, there is no css solution. Only way you can do that is by adding a span and styling it pretending it was a button.

Comment: Because a span doesn't have browser-specific mouse events. I said that there isn't a css solution available, but in fact, there is: you can put in your css `pointer-events: none;` inside your `#a ~ label button`. But you'll see that this approach will prevent the button animation.

Comment: @businas , add that to your answer , and i'll accept

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you click the `button` not `checkbox`. So i updated your HTML, replaced `button` with `span`, its work like a charm. If you must keep button, you need a little javascript code checking checkbox when button clicking.

I'd updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ebilgin/xtayoqmr/6/

HTML

```
<input type=checkbox id="a">
<label for="a">
    <span>Click me</span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
#a {
    display: none;
}
#a + label span {
    background:yellow
}
#a:checked + label span {
    background:red
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/xtayoqmr/4/

CSS:

```
#a ~ label button {
    background:yellow
}
#a:checked ~ label button {
    background:red
}
```

First, get rid of the `display:none` css rule for `#a`. If the input is hidden, how can you toggle it?

With your existing code:
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/xtayoqmr/5/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked id="a" />
<label for="a">
    <button>click me</butto>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
#a {
    display:none;
}
#a ~ label button {
    background:yellow;
}
#a:checked ~ label button {
    background:red;
}
```

If you add attribute `checked` to input, your code works as expected.

Comment: is't clicking the label also suppose to toggle the checkbox ?

Comment: For that, input needs to be inside the label or the label must have a for attribute which contains the id of the input. Input should be the next sibling  of label

Answer (score 1):

Problem seems that the click event is consumed by button and it is not reached to label hence the check box checked state is not toggled. Hence you get it working without button.

Possible solution is using script to trigger click on parent label on click of button.

If you are still looking for css solution then you below is a work around without ***button***.

```css
input.btn {
  display: none;
}
input.btn + label {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #f4f4f4;
  font-family: Calibri;
  border: 1px ridge #ccc;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px;
}
input.btn + label:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px;
  background: #f6f6f6;
}
input.btn + label:active {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px inset;
}
input.btn:checked + label {
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px inset;
  background: #f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="a1" class='btn' />
<label for="a1">Click me</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="a2" class='btn' />
<label for="a2">Click me</label>
```